# How do I change the views scriptPath in the Zend Framework config?

Tags: zend-framework, path, view, config, ini

Since there is absolutely NO DOCUMENTATION on the general config of the Zend Framework - which pisses me off sincerely! - I have to ask this here =(

I want to change the directory structure of my application. I want views and helpers and layouts etc located elsewhere (not the defaults). I know I can change that on the View object, when I have the view object, but that's just silly. This is a config option. In my config (`application.ini`) I have:

```
resources.view[] =
```

which makes a View object available at all times (perfect). How do I config it **in the** `application.ini` **config file**?

Thanks!

*PS. I know I could extend the Controller and create a View object there and config it, but that's not what I want. Config should be in the config file. Period.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

```
resources.view[] =
```

Do this

```
resources.view.scriptPath = "/your/path/"
```

Try and check it by using the following on your view object

```
getScriptPaths()
```

Comment: Hello @jakenoble, i think that comment ";" at end of `resources.view.scriptPath = "/your/path/";` is unnecessary :)

Comment: Ah, I will remove. It's probably force of habit in PHP